# How do I cause a Lightning Web Component on a Lighting Record Page to update when the record is modified

Tags: lightning-web-components, approval-process

I am developing a Lightning Web Component that will display a custom Approval History list. Basically, I am rebuilding the out-of-the-box Approval History related list. Why? Long story.

So I built the component and the APEX to pull the data and everything is working fine. I added the component to an Opportunity Lightning Record Page. When you view an opportunity that has been submitted for approval, the history shows just fine.

The issue I am having is when you view an opportunity that has not yet been submitted for approval. When I click the "Submit for Approval" button, I would like the custom component to refresh, which it is not.

I have created a DateTime field on Opportunity and I set up each approval step to update this field hoping that I could tie into some lifecycle event and update the component. But I'm a little lost on how to tie everything together.

Worst case scenario, I guess I can just use a JS setTimeout, but that seems a little too hacky and not that performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your component reactive by using the [lightning emp api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) or [Change Data Capture](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/change-data-capture/understand-change-data-capture). They both use [CometD](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/BayeauxProtocolAndCometD.htm).

Another option would be to fire an event, considering that the component is on the same page, which would trigger a method in your component to fetch the data with [refreshApex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_salesforce_modules)

Which approach you chose mostly depends on/if you expect the component to refresh when someone else does a change to the record, and 2 users or more need to view an updated component, or only 1 user.

Comment: >"Another option would be to fire an event, considering that the component is on the same page, which would trigger a method in your component to fetch the data with [refreshApex][4]"  This is what I was thinking to do. I just don't understand how I can create an event when the record is updated given that the edit, save, submit for approval and so on are actions that are native to the lightning record page and not a custom component that I am developing.

Comment: Ended up going with the emo api. The only thing is I was not able to set up a process builder to publish a platform event on submit for approval. Fortunately, in my case I am kicking off the approval from a flow so I can publish the event from there.